# move water based on the user inputted value

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

I have a svg of water vessel. The concept is the user will provide min and max range for the water vessel. If it reaches to min level, the color of water level should be shown red which i could do but how can i change the value as per the user given value. The upper level is the max part and lower level is the min part.

The path element made me difficult to change the water level. I know the d attribute of path should be change but how to adapt the d attribute with the user value.

```
    <script>
      const MIN = 0;
      const MAX = 100;
      // if it is near to minimum, color should be change to Red
      var svg = Snap('#svg');
      const s = Snap('#waterLevel');
      const path = Snap('#path-3');
      document.getElementById('inputValue').addEventListener('change', function(event){
        path.attr({
          d: `M140.79,105 L${event.target.value}`
        });
       if (event.target.value === "50") {
         console.log('yes');
         s.attr({
           fill: 'red'
         });
       }
      })
  </script>
```

Here is the updated jsbin example with translate(0,0) used

http://jsbin.com/pocicozini/1/edit?html,output

Answer (score 0):

Rather than change the shape of the path, I would be tempted to take an alternate approach. You could use a clipPath which clips the liquid, and change how high the clip is.

The core of the code would look like this..

```
document.getElementById('inputValue').addEventListener('change', function(event){

   Snap.animate(200-Snap.select("#rectclip").attr('y'),event.target.value, 
      function( val ) { 
         Snap.select("#rectclip").attr({ y: 200 - val  }); 
      }, 50 );
});
```

So we place a rect over the liquid, and adjust the y value so it changes how much of the liquid path is clipped.

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/fadayepire/1/edit?html,output)

Comment: Your approach seems most efficient and professional i think. Is there any technique to move the water level like the water is flowing?

Comment: https://codepen.io/evatoth/pen/xwZoNa this one. The water waving effect.

Comment: Not quite sure how that would look in a full jar, it works well there as it's partly hidden..do you really want water moving like that in a jar ? I'd ask a new question for that one.